# Compiling apk for Android in unity spoils the 3d model

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, apk

Maybe someone knows what it might be? Look at this Ivi model in the editor, everything is fine there, but when the game is compiled on my Xiaomi we get this (1 picture)
[image]

[image: ity]

The problem is in the animation of the model, if you remove the animation of this model, then everything is fine. In unity, everything is always good, but there are problems on the smartphone. I do not know what to do.

Answer (score 0):

There might be a lot of things that cause this. First of all, you should check `Mesh Compression` in your mesh import settings. You should also check your 3d model for these artifacts. It might also be because of how different phones render 3d models. You should try it on a variety of phones and see if it has similar artifacts.

Comment: Opened the app in
NoxPlayer is the same